# Invariant subspace of the standard $p-1$-dimensional representation of the symmetric group $S_p$ in charecteristic $p$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $p \geq 3$ be a prime and consider the standard representation $V$ of the symmetric group $S_p$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$: the representation $(\mathbb{F}_p \cdot e_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{F}_p \cdot  e_p)/\mathbb{F}_p \cdot (e_1+\cdots+e_p)$, where $S_p$ acts by permuting the basis vectors $e_i$. Is there a copy of the trivial representation inside $V$, i.e. are there non-trivial vectors fixed by the entire $S_p$? If so, do there exist formulas to write them down? I'd also be interested in what's known for small values of $p$, say $p=3$ or $p=5$. I'm not very familiar with modular representation theory. Do MAGMA or Sage have packages for answering questions like this for fixed values of $p$?

Comment: If $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_p)$ is not $0$ in the quotient, then $x$ is not of the form $(t,\cdots,t)$ in the original space, so $x_i\ne x_j$ for some $i,j$. If $x$ is also fixed in the quotient, then the difference $(ij)x-x$ must be $0$ in the quotient, which means all its coordinates are equal in the original space. Thus $x_i-x_j=x_j-x_i$, so $1=-1$, so $p=2$: then the quotient is the trivial $1$D rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that up to scaling this vector $e_1 + e_2 + ... +e_p$ is the only invariant vector in $\mathbb{F}_p^p$, this is pretty easy to check directly.

Now suppose there were an invariant vector in this quotient. Let's look at its inverse image in $\mathbb{F}_p^p$, this is a two dimensional subrepresentation where we have one invariant vector and if we quotient by that vector we get another trivial action.

Let's look at this 2 dimensional subspace, with basis given by $e_1 + e_2 + ... +e_p$ and an inverse image of the invariant vector in the quotient. Expanding in this basis, this representation gives a homomorphism from $S_p$ to the group of two by two matrices of the form: \begin{pmatrix}
1 & * \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
This group is just $\mathbb{F}_p^+ = C_p$, and it's not hard to see there are no nontrivial homomorphisms $S_p \to C_p$ (unless $p=2$). However if that homomorphism is trivial then that would mean our second basis vector is actually another invariant vector inside $\mathbb{F}_p^p$, which we know is impossible.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, note that if $V= \mathsf k^n$ viewed as a representation of $S_n$ acting by letting $S_n$ permute the coordinates, then there are two fairly obvious subrepresentations:

1. the hyperplane $H= \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathsf k^n: x_1+\ldots + x_n=0\}$,
2. the line $L=\mathsf k.(1,1,\ldots,1)$, on which $S_n$ acts trivially.

If $W$ is any nonzero subrepresentation, then there is some $w \in W\backslash \{0\}$. If $w=(w_1,\ldots,w_n)$ and all the $w_i$ are equal, then $w \in L$, and so either $W=L$ or there is some $w \in W$ with $w_i\neq w_j$ for some $i,j$ $1\leq i,j \leq n$. But then $w -s_{ij}(w) =(w_i-w_j)(e_i-e_j)$ (where $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ denote the standard basis of $\mathsf k^n$) and so, since $w_i-w_j\neq 0$, $W$ contains $e_i-e_j$. But then it is easy to see that $W$ contains $e_i-e_k$ for any $k \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and hence $H\subseteq W$.

Thus $V$ has exactly two proper subrepresentations, $W$ and $L$. If $\text{char}(\mathsf k)=p$ and $p$ does not divide $n$, then $L\cap H = \{0\}$ and hence $V = H \oplus L$ is completely reducible. (Note that $p \nmid n$ is a much weaker condition that $p \nmid |S_n|=n!$) On the other hand, if $p\mid n$, then $L\subseteq H$, and so $V$ cannot be completely reducible. Indeed since $V/H$ is also isomorphic to the trivial representation (in any characteristic) we see that, when $p\mid \mathrm{char}(\mathsf k)$, $V$ has two composition factors: the trivial representation with multiplicity $2$, corresponding to $L$ and $V/H$, and one copy of the $(n-2)$-dimensional irreducible representation $H/L$.

Note that $H/L$ cannot be the trivial representation for dimension reasons unless $p=3$, but in that case it is easy to check directly that then $H/L$  is the sign representation, and in fact those are the only irreducible representation of $\mathsf k[S_3]$ when $\mathrm{char}(\mathsf k)=3$.

Thus the answer to the question "is there a copy of the trivial representation in $V/L$ depends on whether by "copy of" you mean "a subrepresentation isomorphic to" or "a composition factor isomorphic to". In the former case the answer is no, in the latter it is yes if $p\mid n$.